# UITextField is not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've been working on my app for a little while now, but I ran into a problem that seem so simple today. It probably just something stupid, but I couldn't find out. SO, please help.

I have a `UITextField` that has been connected to `IBOutlet` property.
In `viewDidLoad`,

```
self.myTextFied.text = @"123";
```

This line of code works.
But in a method triggered by `self.delegate`, updating `myTextField.text` doesn't update the UI.

```
self.myTextFied.text = @"345";
NSLog(@"%@",self.myTextField.text);
```

`NSLog` of `self.myTextField.text` shows 345.
Does anyone know what's the reason and how to fix?

Comment: self.myTextField.text = @"345"; It was something else, but I changed it to 345 for testing.

Comment: my question is where you setting the value to textfield?

Comment: Did you check in debugger that your text field isn't `null` and that you have connected it with IB properly?

Comment: @nsgulliver self.myTextField.text = @"345"; It was something else, but I changed it to 345 for testing.And NSLog of self.myTextField.Text shows 345.

Comment: @matejkramny I checked in debugger, and it's not null.

Comment: I'm definitely missing something... you set it to "345", then log it and the value shows as "345". The problem is...?

Comment: @BillPatterson Sorry for the confusion. It's not updating the UI.

Comment: And you're giving the event loop a chance to redraw the UI? Also, if you log the text field object after your "this works" line and also after your "this doesn't work" line, it's definitely showing the same object? That is: `NSLog(@"Text object is: %@", self.myTextField);`

Comment: What "method triggered by self.delegate" are you referring to?

Comment: You say it's not updating the UI.  What is the output of `NSLog(@"window=%@", self.myTextField.window);`?

Comment: Edit: Nevermind. I was confusing comment threads. [Was: "It prints the default description of the argument, which shows you a string that can be treated for these purposes as an object id. Try it and you'll see."]

Comment: nothing helpful so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the `UITextView` the chance to get updated. The UI is running on a single thread and might therefore not get updated as long as your delegate method did still not finish. Hard to say without more information. You might have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730691/how-to-repaint-a-uitextview-for-iphone-3-x-after-updating-data-programatically) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should check if you updating your interface in main thread - if using gcd
Try calling self.setNeedsLayout